# Fix the middle category in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, categories

I have a bar graph with 3 groups, each with 3 fill categories. I want one category to always be the middle category on the bar graph.

```
dat <- data.frame(fill=c("Category A","Category B","Middle",
                      "Category A","Category C","Middle",
                      "Category B","Category C","Middle"),
                  x=c("A","A","A",
                      "B","B","B",
                      "C","C","C"),
                  y=c(.333,.333,.333,
                      .4,.4,.2,
                      .2,.4,.4))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=fill))+
  geom_col()
```

I don't think this is possible with traditional factor ordering because I can't set the `Middle` category to be the middle of each combination:

```
dat$fill <- factor(dat$fill,levels=c("Category A","Middle","Category B","Category C"))
```

If I do this, `Middle` will fall between `Category A` and `Category B`, but not between `Category B` and `Category C`.

[image]

Is it possible to set one category to always be the middle category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(fill=="Middle", 2, c(1,3)))%>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=fill, group=n))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

The `mutate` will add the column you can use for your group ranked by order. The `ifesle` will give the row with "Middle" 2, and when false 1 and 3. In this case it is convenient as each group have 3 categories. This part will need change if you have more categories per group.

```
dat %>% group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(fill=="Middle", 2, c(1,3)))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   x [3]
  fill       x         y     n
  <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Category A A     0.333     1
2 Category B A     0.333     3
3 Middle     A     0.333     2
4 Category A B     0.4       1
5 Category C B     0.4       3
6 Middle     B     0.2       2
7 Category B C     0.2       1
8 Category C C     0.4       3
9 Middle     C     0.4       2
```

#### Update: Middle with different categories per group:

Here is an option to have a specific category always in the middle of the stacked histograms:

```
dat %>% group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(fill=="Middle", round(median(1:n())), c(1:(round(median(1:n()))-1),(round(median(1:n()))+1):n()))) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=fill, group=n))+
  geom_col(position="fill")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(colorRampPalette(c("grey10", "grey80"))(14), "red"))
```

[image]

#### Data

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(14)

dat = data.frame(
  fill = c(
    c(sample(paste0("Cat ", letters[1:20]), 20, replace = TRUE), "Middle"),
    c(sample(paste0("Cat ", letters[1:20]), 10, replace = TRUE), "Middle"),
    c(sample(paste0("Cat ", letters[1:20]), 2, replace = TRUE), "Middle")),
  x= c(rep("A", 21), rep("B", 11), rep("C", 3)),
  y= runif(35))
```

Comment: I was wondering if an ifelse statement might be the answer but couldn't figure out how to apply it. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for the addition that explains this. I imagine a longer `case_when` statement (instead of `ifelse`) could solve this when there's 4+ categories.

Comment: You can use this: `mutate(n = ifelse(fill=="Middle", 2, c(1,3:n())))`, in this instance Middle will always be in position number 2 then all the rest is label 3 to `n()` number of row in the group

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you! I wouldn't have thought to use 3:n()

Comment: You can use this trick to always have the specific category in the middle regardless of the number of categories within each group. I updated the answer to show an example and the code